# Is there a Linear Map to represent transpose?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

For example,
I want $AB = A^T$, is there such a matrix $B$ that does this? Where $A$ is $n \times m$ and $B$ is $m \times n$.

Comment: But then, $AB$ is $nxn$ and the transpose of A is $mxn$.

Comment: As said in other comments it must be $m=n.$ In other case $B$ doesn't exist by dimension reasons. If $A$ is invertible then you have $B=A^{-1}A^T.$ If $A$ is singular then you can't expect to have such a $B,$ as shown by @BaronVT in his answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $A$ is $m\times n$ and $B$ is $n\times m$, then $AB$ is $m\times m$. On the other hand, $A^T$ is $n\times m$. Therefore one immediately sees that for $m\ne n$, there cannot be a $B$ with that property.

Therefore let's in the following assume $m=n$.

We have
$$A = (A^T)^T = (AB)^T = (AB)B = AB^2$$
for *all* $A$, which is only possible if $B^2=I$, where $I$ is the $n\times n$ identity matrix.

On the other hand, since $B$ is supposed to transpose *all* $n\times n$ matrices, but $B$ itself is an $n\times n$ matrix, we also have
$$B^T = BB = I.$$
In other words, $B$ is the identity matrix. But that means that
$$A^T = AB = AI = A$$
for all $n\times n$ matrices $A$. However this is only true if $n=1$.

Therefore apart from the trivial case of $1\times 1$ matrices, there's no matrix $B$ with that property.

However, if you consider the matrix space itself as vector space, then the transposition itself is indeed a linear map, since $(\alpha A + \beta B)^T = \alpha A^T + \beta B^T$. However you cannot write that map as a single matrix. But if you accept more complicated expressions, you can indeed explicitly write down the transpose map:

Assume $A$ is an $m\times n$ matrix. Be $E_{ij}$ the $n\times m$ matrix which has an entry $1$ in line $i$ and column $j$, and all other entries $0$. Then you can write
$$A^T = \sum_{i,j} E_{ij} \operatorname{tr} \left(E_{ij} A\right)$$
where $\operatorname{tr} X$ is the trace of $X$, that is, the sum of all diagonal elements.

This works as follows: Multiplying $A$ (which I'll assume to have matrix elements $a_{i,j}$) from the left with $E_{ij}$ gives an $n\times n$ matrix that has the $j$-th row of $A$ in the $i$-th row, and $0$ in all other rows. Therefore the only non-zero diagonal element is the one in row/column $i$, which contains the element $a_{ji}$. Multiplying that with $E_{ij}$ gives a $n\times m$ matrix that has $a_{ji}$ in row $i$, column $j$ and is $0$ otherwise. Adding over $i$ and $j$ finally gets you a matrix that for every $i$ and $j$ contains $a_{ji}$ in row $i$, column $j$, that is, $A^T$.

Answer (score 2):

There can be no such $B$ that does this for all $A$. For example, if $A = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$

then

$$
AB = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}B = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}
$$

is impossible for any $B$.

Comment: This is for $2\times 2$ case. What about say, $1\times 3$?

Comment: If $A$ is $1\times 3$, and $B$ is $3 \times 1$, then $AB$ is $1\times 1$, and cannot be equal to $A^T$ (similarly if $A$ is $3 \times 1$, then $AB$ is $3 \times 3$, etc.)

Comment: I see, this is quite hopeless. Even without that restriction on   $B$, the dimensions of $AB$ can't match the dimensions of $A^T$ when $m\ne n$.

Comment: Note that, for instance, $2\times 2$-matrices operate on $\mathbb{R}^2$, while trensposition operates on the linear space of $2\times 2$-matrices. So you need an linear operator **on that space**, and that cannot be a $2\times 2$-matrix, you would have to try with an $4\times 4$-matrix, combined with stacking the matrix as a vector (the $\text{vec}$-operator).

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen multiplication be a $2\times2$ matrix **is** a particular kind of linear transformation on the $2\times 2$ matrices, so these matrices **can** operate on the space of $2\times2$ matrices. It just so happens that the transpose operation is a linear transformation that can't be represented in this particular way.

Comment: Well, very few linear transformations of matrices can be represented in that form!

Comment: If you investigate linear transformation of matrices which can be represented in such fashion by multiplication with a given matrix, they will typically **not** be normal transformations, while transposition surely is normal, it is an orthogonal transformation with all eigenvalues equal to one. I leave that for you to investigate!